# What is the best way to remove a third-party Django app with models in database?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a third-party application in my Django project that I'd like to remove. My problem is that if I simply remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS`, all the models and associated tables that it created in my database will be kept.

I know I can manually DROP thoses tables afterwards but I want this to be automated (since there are multiple running instances of this project, I don't want to ask people to run any manual command when upgrading). I'm wondering if there is a recommended or "clean" way to do so with Django migrations.

I created a migration file in one of my apps (the one that used this third-party app) with a `migrations.DeleteModel(name='ThirdPartyModel')` but it fails to execute because this model is managed by the other app.

What is left it to write a RunSQL migration whith a `DROP TABLE thirdpartyapp_thirdpartymodel` and a `DELETE FROM django_content_type WHERE app_label = thirdpartyapp AND model = thirdpartymodel`.

Is there any other option? How are these types of operations supposed to be done?

I'm using Django 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure none of your models have any dependency to this third party app, so no foreign keys, one to one fields, many to many relations, etc. Remove any of these and migrate.

Next you want to migrate the changes this app made to `zero` so you can run the following command:

```
python manage.py migrate <third_party_appname> zero
```

Referred from the documentation on [`migrate` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#migrate):

> **<app_label> <migrationname>**: Brings the database schema to a state where the named migration is applied, but no later migrations in the
> same app are applied. This may involve unapplying migrations if you
> have previously migrated past the named migration. You can use a
> prefix of the migration name, e.g. 0001, as long as it’s unique for
> the given app name. Use the name **zero** to migrate all the way back
> i.e. to revert all applied migrations for an app.

This will revert all changes made to the database and now you can freely remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mention it explicitly but I'd like not to have any need for manual intervention for this. There are multiple running instances of the Django project and I don't want to ask people to run this command after upgrading. This should be done automatically when upgrading. Will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @BrunoParmentier don't see any elegant way if that is the case, you can only use the raw SQL as you suggest.

Comment: @BrunoParmentier you can try using a `RunPython` in your migration that uses `call_command` to call a management command. See [Running management commands from your code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code) but I don't know if that will work.

Comment: In my case, I really wanted a migration that performed the removal since I wanted to ensure consistency across different environments and wanted to have some history of when we dropped the tables. I resorted to manually printing out the reverse SQL of each migration and using that as a `RunSQL` migration to remove the tables.